# SQLite table with some rows missing a column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table in a SQLite database that looks something like this, but with more columns and rows:

```
| Field1  | Field2  |
|---------|---------|
| A       | 1       |
| B       | 2       |
| C       |         |
```

What I need to do is run a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <conditions> ORDER BY Field2
```

The problem is, I'm getting the error: `no such column: Field2`

So now I've been asked to set all the missing values to 99. But when I run

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET Field2='99' WHERE Field2 IS NULL;
```

I get the same error. How do I fix this and update all those missing cells?

EDIT: I should also add that the missing values don't seem to be null since if I add a new column in my database GUI browser, all the cells show as `[NULL]`, though this column doesn't.

Comment: What is the real name of the column ? Perhaps it's a reserved word

Comment: try to quote the column and see if it helps

Comment: @Ryx5 it is `sortOrder`. Though other tables in the same database use it and work fine.

Comment: Please show the actual creation statement for the table and the query you are using.

Comment: Yes, I have done some research in most of the time, the code of app doesn't write sql as espected, can you show the full code please? (table creation + sql statement creation)

Comment: @GordonLinoff @Ryx5, I didn't create the table. It was given to me as a `.sqlite` file. And the update statement is exactly as I posted except for the table name and the field name (which as I commented before is `sortOrder`.

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7eff9/2). Show how your table is different.

Comment: @CL but that's just it, I don't know how it's different. It's like some of the rows don't have that column. Like I said, this was just a `.sqlite` file I was given.

Comment: @CL That empty field isn't NULL and it's not an empty string. It simply doesn't exist in certain rows.

Comment: The `no such column` error has nothing to do with these values. As for the values, show the output of `SELECT DISTINCT typeof(Field2) FROM MyTable`.

Comment: @CL I get the same error: `no such column: Field2`. I'm also noticing I'm getting that error for another column that exists in a different table in this same database. That column has values in every row.

Comment: Show the complete table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a very subtle problem in the table:

Several of the column names (the ones that were causing me problems) ended in a newline (`\n`). Removing the newline solved all my problems!